# error: no suitable method found for add(ArrayList<Integer>) greatestCd.add(numFactors);

Tags: java

I am making a fraction calculator in java for school. I am trying to find the greatest common divisor using arrays ,but I keep getting an error telling me there is no suitable method found for add(ArrayList) .Basicaly what I am trying to do is add the numbFactors arraylist and denFactors arraylist to the greatestCd arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numFactors = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> denFactors = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> greatestCd = new ArrayList<>();

// reduce the fraction result.
// find the factors of the numerator and denominator. check
for(int i = 2; i < rn +1; ++i){
    //check if the factors go evenly. check
    if (rn%i == 0){
        numFactors.add(i);
    }

}

//Same for denominators. check
for(int i = 2; i < rd +1; ++i){
    //check if the factors go evenly. check
    if (rd%i == 0){
        denFactors.add(i);
    }

}
//Find the greatest common divisor
//Find the common factors
for(int i =0; i < numFactors.size(); i++){
    for(int j =0; j<denFactors.size(); j++){
        if(numFactors == denFactors){

           greatestCd.add(numFactors);
           greatestCd.add(denFactors);
        }
// check to see which are the same
// if they are, add them to the third arraylist
    }
}
```

here is the error I am getting

```
 error: no suitable method found for add(ArrayList<Integer>)
                                                greatestCd.add(numFactors);
                                                          ^
    method Collection.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method List.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method AbstractCollection.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method AbstractList.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method ArrayList.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
RodriguesP1.java:159: error: no suitable method found for add(ArrayList<Integer>)

                                                greatestCd.add(denFactors);
                                                          ^
    method Collection.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method List.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method AbstractCollection.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method AbstractList.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
    method ArrayList.add(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
```

Comment: You probably want to use `numFactors.get(i)` and `denFactors.get(j)` respectively

Comment: whats the difference between get and add?

Comment: No, i meant e.g. `greatestCd.add(numFactors.get(i));` and `if(numFactors.get(i) == denFactors.get(j))`

Comment: I don't get your last `if` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on this line `greatestCd.add(numFactors);` you are trying to add an ArrayList to another ArrayList (Which expects only Integers, not another ArrayList of Integers).

What you probably want to do is to add all elements from `numFactors` to `greatestCd`. use .addAll().

`greatestCd.addAll(numFactors);`

Or for your example, add just one from numFactors using .get(index).

`greatestCd.add(numFactors.get(i));`